# Distributed json loading in force collapsable layout

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am quite new to D3 and will really appreciate some help. I am trying to modify this force collapsible layout

https://bitbucket.org/kolbyjAFK/d3/src/f87f85b9c6e2/examples/force/force-collapsible.html

The data it loads is in single json file 
https://bitbucket.org/kolbyjAFK/d3/src/f87f85b9c6e236f20dec8151ae11438950aaf967/examples/data/flare.json?at=fix-interpolate-hsl

But what if i have a data which i dont want to load in a go. I want to call the children only when the user clicks on a particular node.

So i basically want to modularize json so that when a node is clicked, json file containing the array of children loads dynamically.

I need to do this as my data is huge, 500k leaf node.

How could i do this dynamic loading?

Comment: can you please elaborate on the approach. I am using d3 for the first time.

Comment: Well my data is way to big to load all at once. I want to call different files. Hide and show is already implemented. 
But i m not able to understand how will i modify the update function in 
https://bitbucket.org/kolbyjAFK/d3/src/f87f85b9c6e2/examples/force/force-collapsible.html
as what i think is that this update function take in consideration that we load whole tree at once.

Comment: Here is what exactly i m looking for:
**When i click on a node. A json containing its nodes gets loaded.**
I can do that but what i dont know is how should i link these nodes to its parents.
Kindly help on this

Comment: Well, if you use `d3.json`, it creates a JSON object for you to use. I suspect that the correct approach would be appending that object to the `children` array in your parent node whenever a node is clicked. If you have a `filename: _value_` object for each node in your structure, you can use it as a parameter for the `onclick`, create the _child_ object from the filename you passed with the `d3.json` function, and then, inside the `onclick` function, append the _child_ object you created to the `children` array of the node you clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To maybe help you get started, the `click` function in your code is the key to solve this.

Right now it looks like this:

```js
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update();
}
```

This only hides/shows the nodes in your structure by moving them between two different arrays: `children` when they visible; `_children` when they are not.

What you might want to try is:

- make sure that in your JSON data, each `node` object has a `filename: _fileNameString_` object in it. (like you have `name: _nodeName_` right now in the JSON you are loading)
- then, your `click` function would have to do something like:

  ```js
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else if (!d.children && !d._children) {
      var nameOfTheFile = d.filename;
      var childObject = d3.json(nameOfTheFile);
      d.children.push(childObject);
    } else {
       d.children = d._children;
       d._children = null;
    }
    update();    
  }
  ```

Please note that I haven't tested this, so I'm not sure if it works or not, but I think that this approach might be feasible.

**EDIT:**
Also note this assumes that your whole data is already distributed throughout several files. So, the `flare.json` file, or whatever you use first to load you first JSON data has this structure:

```json
{
  "name": "flare",
  "filename": "children1.json",
  "children": [ ]
}
```

And the `children1.json` could be something like:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "cluster",
    "filename": "children2.json",
    "children": [ ]
  },
  {
    "name": "graph",
    "filename": "children3.json",
    "children": [ ]
  },
  {
    "name": "optimization",
    "filename": "children4.json",
    "children": [ ]
  }
]
```

And so on... Bottom line, you already have to have your data *distributed* somehow in these files with the structure you want/need.

Comment: I forgot to add that in the `click()` function, you should check if the node has `fileName`, otherwise it might hang... Did you account for that in your solution?

Comment: yes i already implemented that.. we just have load the json with some sanity checks in the click function and change the children accordingly.. 
thanks a lot man!!

Comment: I am new to d3 i tried what you said but the children's are not showing in the click, any examples appreciated

Comment: @mcbalaji maybe you should ask your own question and place your code there. It might be a different subject/problem. Also, what is the output in the console?