# d3.js on-demand data loading to get the next node for a tree

Tags: ajax, d3.js, tree, onclick, expand

I am trying to use this example in D3 (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025), which is the expanding tree. From all the examples I see all the data is always loaded from a single JSON dataset.

The issue I am facing is that the data could potentially drill down into many, many nodes and the JSON would be huge...

Is there a way to make an ajax call when the user clicks on a branch and then add the data to the set and exapnd the tree branch?

thanks in advance

Matt

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You would just need to rerun the tree layout with the new data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are there any examples out there?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for a very similar solution like you and solved my problem by doing this.

In the given example (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025) you have a `click` method:

```
// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
     d._children = d.children;
     d.children = null;
  } else {
     d.children = d._children;
     d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

I changed the given one a bit:

```
 function click(d) {

          if (!d.children && !d._children) {

              var nameOfTheFile = d.jsonPath;
              var childObjects;

                 d3.json(nameOfTheFile, function(error, json) {

                    childObjects = json; 
                    childObjects.forEach(function(node) {
                            if(node.name != d.name){
                                (d._children || (d._children = [])).push(node);
                            }
                        });

                    if (d.children) {
                        d._children = d.children;
                        d.children = null;
                     } else {
                        d.children = d._children;
                        d._children = null;
                    }   
                    update(d);

                   }); 


          } else {
              if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
              } else {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d._children = null;
              }
              update(d);    
          }

  }
```

**Explanation**:
I have added a property to my node where the a rest service URL is defined which returns me a JSON file with the children of the given node (Here you can also place the path to the JSON file itself). If the given node in the `click(d)` method does not have any children in his array then I read the property and call the URL to extract his children. The returned children I push to the `d._children` array and run the normal logic (also the update method).

So you can load the childs of a node on demand without having one big JSON file. For me it is a very good solution. Thanks to [Distributed json loading in force collapsable layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962350/distributed-json-loading-in-force-collapsable-layout), where the idea comes from.