# d3 load data for next node on click

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to get data on click for draw child node.
I've already read the answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185756/d3-js-on-demand-data-loading-to-get-the-next-node-for-a-tree).

However, it seems like children nodes that are added on click can't find the parent node.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwd2J.png)

Here's my entire code:

```
    var hierarchy = d3.layout.hierarchy().children(function(d) {
    return d.childCi;
});

function parseLevel(node, level) {
    node.level = level;
    if (typeof node.children !== 'undefined') {
        node.children.forEach(function(children) {
            parseLevel(children, level + 1);
        });
    }
}

var COLLAPSE_LEVEL = 1;

var width = 960, height = 500, root;

var force = d3.layout.force().linkDistance(80).charge(-120).gravity(.05)
        .size([ width, height ]).on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("#canvas-svg").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr(
        "height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),

node = svg.selectAll(".node");

d3.json("graph.json", function(error, json) {
    if (error)
        throw error;

    hierarchy(json);
    root = json;
    update();
    parseLevel(root, 0);
    //collapseAll();
    root.children.forEach(collapseAll);
});

function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}

function collapseAll(d) {

    if (d.children) {
        d.children.forEach(collapseAll);
        if (d.level < COLLAPSE_LEVEL) {
            return;
        }
        collapse(d);
        update();
    }
}

function update() {
    var nodes = flatten(root), links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
    console.log(links);

    // Restart the force layout.
    force.nodes(nodes).links(links).start();

    // Update links.
    link = link.data(links, function(d) {
        return d.target.id;
    });

    link.exit().remove();

    link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");

    // Update nodes.
    node = node.data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id;
    });

    node.exit().remove();

    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").attr("class", "node").on(
            "click", click).call(force.drag);

    nodeEnter.append("circle").attr("r", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 10;
    });

    nodeEnter.append("text").attr("dy", ".35em").text(function(d) {
        return d.ciName;
    });

    nodeEnter.append("text").attr("dy", ".35em").attr("y", -10).text(
            function(d) {

                if (d.childBox) {

                    console.log('d.childBox[0].childCiCount'
                            + d.childBox[0].childCiCount);
                    return d.childBox[0].childCiCount;
                }

                if (d.children)
                    return d.children.length;
                else if (d._children)
                    return d._children.length;
                else
                    return '';
            });

    node.select("circle").style("fill", color);
}

function tick() {

    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
    }).attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
    }).attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
    }).attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
    });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
}

function color(d) {

    if (d._children) {
        return "#3182bd";
    } else if (d.children) {
        return "#c6dbef";
    } else {
        if (d.ciStatusLevel == 1) {
            console.log("ciStatusLevel:" + d.ciStatusLevel);
            return "#FFF173";
        }

        return "#fd8d3c";
    }

    /* return d._children ? "#3182bd" // collapsed package
     : d.children ? "#c6dbef" // expanded package
     : "#fd8d3c"; // leaf node */
}

//Toggle children on click.
/* function click(d) {
 if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag

 if (d.children) {
 d._children = d.children;
 d.children = null;
 } else {
 d.children = d._children;
 d._children = null;
 }
 update();


 }
 */

function click(d) {

    if (!d.children && !d._children) {

        var nameOfTheFile = 'data/test1.json';
        var childObjects;

        d3.json(nameOfTheFile, function(error, json) {

            childObjects = json;

            console.log(childObjects);
            childObjects.forEach(function(node) {

                if (node.ciName != d.ciName) {
                    (d._children || (d._children = [])).push(node);

                }

            });

            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } else {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }
            update(d);

        });

    } else {
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
        } else {
            d.children = d._children;
            d._children = null;
        }
        update(d);
    }

}

//Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [], i = 0;

    function recurse(node) {
        if (node.children) {
            node.children.forEach(recurse);
        }
        if (!node.id) {
            node.id = ++i;
        }
        nodes.push(node);

    }

    recurse(root);
    return nodes;
}
```

P.S: I'm using the force layout(https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. The relationship is top-down, i.e. the parent node holds a reference to its children but the children know nothing about their parent node. What is your actual problem? What are you expecting? What do you see instead?  Please be as precise as possible. Setting up a [mcve] would be helpful, too.

Comment: My expectation is if I add child objects on click like above it should expand child objects. However, right now it doesn't show. Instead, parent node gets disconnected to its parent.

Comment: Ok I succeeded on adding a new node on click. However, after adding a new node, the graph won't collapse again. What would be the problem..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got a solution!

var target = {id: nodes.length+1, ciName: "test"};

```
        /* console.log('node in click');
        console.log(node);
        console.log('link in click');
        console.log(link); */
         (d._children || (d._children = [])).push(target);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I succeeded on adding a new node on click. However, after adding a new node, the graph won't collapse again. What would be the problem..?

var width = 960, height = 500, root;

```
var force = d3.layout.force().linkDistance(80).charge(-120).gravity(.05)
        .size([ width, height ]).on("tick", tick);



var nodes;
var link, node;

d3.json("graph.json", function(error, json) {
 if (error) throw error;

 root = json;
     nodes = flatten(root), 
links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
 update();
 }); 

function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}

function collapseAll(d) {
    /* collapse(root);
    update(); */

    if (d.children) {
        d.children.forEach(collapseAll);
        if (d.level < COLLAPSE_LEVEL) {
            return;
        }
        collapse(d);
        update();
    }
}

function update() {
    /* nodes = flatten(root), 
    links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
    console.log('nodes');
    console.log(nodes);
    console.log('links');
    console.log(links);

    // Restart the force layout.
    force.nodes(nodes).links(links).start();


    link = svg.selectAll(".link"),

    node = svg.selectAll(".node");



    // Update links.
    link = link.data(links, function(d) {
        return d.target.id;
    });

    link.exit().remove();

    var linkEnter = link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");

    //link = linkEnter.merge(link);

    // Update nodes.
    node = node.data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id;
    });
    node.exit().remove(); 


    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").attr("class", "node").on(
            "click", click).call(force.drag);//click 리스너 추가

    nodeEnter.append("circle").attr("r", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 10;
    });

    nodeEnter.append("text").attr("dy", ".35em").text(function(d) {
        return d.ciName;
    });

    nodeEnter.append("text").attr("dy", ".35em").attr("y", -10).text(
            function(d) {

                if (d.childBox) {

                    console.log('d.childBox[0].childCiCount'
                            + d.childBox[0].childCiCount);
                    return d.childBox[0].childCiCount;
                }

                if (d.children)
                    return d.children.length;
                else if (d._children)
                    return d._children.length;
                else
                    return '';
            });

    node.select("circle").style("fill", color);

    //node = nodeEnter.merge(node);

}

function tick() {

    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
    }).attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
    }).attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
    }).attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
    });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
}

function color(d) {

    if (d._children) {
        return "#3182bd";
    } else if (d.children) {
        return "#c6dbef";
    } else {
        if (d.ciStatusLevel == 1) {
            console.log("ciStatusLevel:" + d.ciStatusLevel);
            return "#FFF173";
        }

        return "#fd8d3c";
    }

    /* return d._children ? "#3182bd" // collapsed package
     : d.children ? "#c6dbef" // expanded package
     : "#fd8d3c"; // leaf node */
}

//Toggle children on click.
/* function click(d) {
 if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag

 if (d.children) {
 d._children = d.children;
 d.children = null;
 } else {
 d.children = d._children;
 d._children = null;
 }
 update();


 }
 */

function click(d) {


    console.log('d');
    console.log(d);

    if (!d.children && !d._children) {


          var target = {id: nodes.length+1, ciName: "test"};

            /* console.log('node in click');
            console.log(node);
            console.log('link in click');
            console.log(link); */
             (d._children || (d._children = [])).push(target);
            nodes.push(target);
            links.push({source: d, target: target});



        if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } else {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            } 
            update(); 



    } else {
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
        } else {
            d.children = d._children;
            d._children = null;
        }
        update();
    }

}

//Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [], i = 0;

    function recurse(node) {
        if (node.children) {
            node.children.forEach(recurse);
        }
        if (!node.id) {
            node.id = ++i;
        }
        nodes.push(node);

    }

    recurse(root);
    return nodes;
}
```